# Solve for the k term (equation)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability

I am currently struggling a lot with understanding how to solve for specific terms in a mathematical expression as soon as it becomes a little bit more "advanced" than just x+y=z (solve x for instance). This might seem like a simple equation, so I hope some can specify to me what I need to do in order to understand this concept.

I have the following equation:

4 = $\frac{1}{1-0,9+0.9/k}$

I need to solve for the k term, which should yield me an answer of k = 6, according to Maple/Wolfram Alpha.

However I have no idea how to end up at that answer from the equation above, I can't seem to make a connection that makes sense to me, no matter how I try to isolate the $\it{k'th}$ term.

Can someone kindly help me to understand how I can solve equations for terms, like the k here. I'm still new to these kind of math problems. I need it to calculate probability issues, in more advanced equations later.

Comment: $1-0.9=\frac {0.9} k+\frac  1 4=0.25$. Can you proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. simplify: $4=\dfrac1{0.1+\dfrac{0.9}k}$;
2. invert: $0.25=0.1+\dfrac{0.9}k$;
3. simplify: $0.15=\dfrac{0.9}k$;
4. invert: $\dfrac1{0.15}=\dfrac k{0.9}$;
5. solve: $k=\dfrac{0.9}{0.15}=6$.

Comment: Thanks, this actually makes sense to me. In (2) term you just invert the fraction from the right hand site right? So 4 becomes 1/4 instead = 0.25?

Comment: @newLearner: seems obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is: $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}+\frac{9}{10k}}=4$$ Doing the $lcm$ and reversing the denominator, I have:$$\frac{10k}{k+9}=4$$
Multiply by $k+9$, I obtain:$$10k=4k+36$$ And so, the solution is: $$k=6$$